# Symfony2 app hangs randomly - tools to debug

Tags: symfony, docker, vps

I have a VPS with two docker containers running on it. The two containers have different source code written using Symfony2 inside. The problem is that one of them randomly hangs and is not responding to any requests. It happens only with one of them so I think it's a problem with the source of the app. There are no error logs or server overload when I try to debug the problem. Everything seems fine. Can you suggest me some tools so I can debug the problem and find solution because this happens 5-6 times a day and lasts between 2 and 5 minutes. Then the container works fine - it fixes alone without restart or anything.

Comment: Have you tried to run the app you think is faulty in the other container?

Comment: I tried to run the container on different server and the problem still exists. The two images are running in containers with the same configuration in Dockerfile, the only difference is that different source folders are mounted while building the image. So the two containers are with identical versions of the dependencies and the environment, the only difference is the source with the Symfony2 source code.

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug is the de facto tool for debugging. There are a lot of tutorials on how to use it. If the hang is caused when you access a route then you should debug that route in particular.